# What is the purpose of => in julia

Tags: julia

From my understanding `=>` used to bound string as a variable name.

For ex,

```
df1 = DataFrame(x=1:2, y= 11: 12)

df2 = DataFrame("x"=>1:2, "y"=> 11: 12)
```

Both returns same result,

```
│ Row │ x     │ y     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 11    │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 12    │
```

Here the only difference is in `df1`'s `x` variable holds `1:2` whereas in `df2`'s `"x"` string holds `1:2`. So, from the above result, I presumed to create variable from string I can use `=>`.

But when I tried holding values in simple variable like below

`x = 10`

O/P: `10`

`"y"=>10`

O/P: `"y" => 10`

This result I couldn't understand. When I print `x` it has `10` as expected. But when I print `y` I am getting `UndefVarError`. I found the same effect with `Symbol` also `:z =>10`

My assumption about `=>` is wrong I guess. Because string is actually not converted as a new variable.

What is the actual purpose of `=>` in julia?
In which I have to use `=>` rather than `=`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To understand what `=>` means just write:

```
@edit 1 => 2
```

and in the source you will see:

```
Pair(a, b) = Pair{typeof(a), typeof(b)}(a, b)
const => = Pair
```

So `a => b` is just a shorthand for `Pair(a, b)`. Therefore it just creates an object of type `Pair` holding `a` and `b`. It is a call (in this case a call to the constructor). That is all to it. It has no special meaning in the language. Just as `1 ÷ 2` is just the same as `div(1, 2)`.

Notably, you will find `=>` used in `Dict` and in DataFrames.jl as in `a => b` form `a` and `b` can be anything. Just to give a comparison:

```
df1 = DataFrame(x=1:2, y=11:12)
```

calls `DataFrame` constructor with two **keyword arguments** `x` and `y`. The issue is that keyword arguments are restricted to be valid identifiers (e.g. they do not allow spaces), so not all data frames that you could envision can be created using this constructor.

Now

```
df2 = DataFrame("x"=>1:2, "y"=>11:12)
```

calls `DataFrame` constructor with two **positional arguments** that are `"x"=>1:2` and `"y"=>11:12`. Now, as `Pair` can hold anything on the left hand side, you can e.g. pass a string as a column name (and a string can contain any sequence of characters you like).

In other words `DataFrame(x=1:2, y=11:12)` and `DataFrame("x"=>1:2, "y"=>11:12)` are calls to two separate constructors of a data frame (they have completely different implementation in DataFrames.jl package). Actually I would even remove `DataFrame(x=1:2, y=11:12)` as obsolete (it is less flexible than the latter form), but it is provided for legacy reasons (and in toy examples it is a bit easier to type).